# Set two elements to the same height

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have one element that I am trying to set to the same height of another, and where the latter element is displayed conditionally using the `*ngIf` directive:

```
<!-- HTML code -->
<my-custom-component #notificationBar *ngIf="notificationMessage">
</my-custom-component>

<ion-content>
  <div style="background: red; width: 100%;"
    [style.height]="notificationBar && notificationBar.nativeElement.offsetHeight">
  </div>
  <!-- .... -->
</ion-content>


//*.ts code
@ViewChild("notificationBar") notificationBar: ElementRef;
```

The problem that I am facing is that I am having the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error when my custom component is displayed:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'height: undefined'. Current value: 'height: 0'.
```

Is there any other proper way to set the two elements to the same height?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The height of the notification bar can be obtained with the help of a property getter. When that height changes, call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` to avoid the exception that would occur when the height is applied to the `div` element.

```
@ViewChild("notificationBar") private notificationBarRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

private _notificationBarHeight: number = null;

public get notificationBarHeight(): number {
  const height = this.notificationBarRef ? this.notificationBarRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight : null;
  if (Math.abs(height - this._notificationBarHeight) > 0.1) {
    this._notificationBarHeight = height;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
  return this._notificationBarHeight;
}
```

In the template, set the height of the `div` element in pixels with the `[style.height.px]` binding:

```
<div ... [style.height.px]="notificationBarHeight">
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcnutm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Working fine. just modification is : this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); does not solve "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError".

we can use "setTimeout" to get rid of this. like:


if (Math.abs(height - this._notificationBarHeight) > 0.1) {

setTimeout(() => {
        this._notificationBarHeight = height;
      });    
    //this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); //not required
  }

Comment: @aru - The `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` does not appear to be triggered in [my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcnutm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: yes , right. it does not triggered in your stackblitz demo. but don't know why, I tried to use your logic - I am still getting `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error so I tried setTimeout() and it's working fine. anyway, thank you for your code, it has really helped me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

SetTimeout() will solve issue of

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

```
    @ViewChild("notificationBar") private notificationBarRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
    
    private _notificationBarHeight: number = null;
    public get notificationBarHeight(): number {
      const height = this.notificationBarRef ? this.notificationBarRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight : null;
    
      if (Math.abs(height - this._notificationBarHeight) > 0.1) {
        setTimeout(() => {
              this._notificationBarHeight = height;  
        });              
      }
      return this._notificationBarHeight;
    }
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your `notificationBarHeight` property will return the old value, before the `setTimeout` callback has had a chance to modify it.